Can you Set Sound to turn off and on at certain times? No third Party Apps available
So, basically I'm lazy. I hate logging off for the day (I don't log out, also lazy, but also I normally have like 20 different things open and opening them all is torture.) only to realize I left the sound on and I'm hearing notifications all night until I make my way into the office to turn it off. But then I forget to turn it back on it the morning and miss stuff.
This is a work computer, so no installations possible. 99% of what I've seen on the net is using third party apps which I have no access or ability to.
I've been looking for a CMD or Powershell command I can run with Task Scheduler as that's been the most promising so far. It's not been fruitful with what I've tried.
There used to be a "Quiet time" in Windows 10 so this wasn't an issue, I just told it what time I was working. Why they got rid of it, no one knows.

Okay, so literally after posting I found the solution. Leaving it in case there are others with the same question but here is the answer:
There was a command that fit on one line for Powershell and was able to do in Task Manager with no admin rights.
So in Task Scheduler, I set the action for the time I wanted every day, and for lowering the volume, I open C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe then I put in the command in the "add arguments" field:
(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string] [char] 174*50)
For increasing the volume, I change the time again and I put:
(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string] [char] 175*50)

Nice, but worth noting that the command for increasing the volume does so to a 100%. For the sake of completeness: (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string][char] 173) can be used to toggle the mute status (though your approach is better from a desired-state perspective).
